# How to draw underline to a multiline label without using CoreText?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, uilabel, underline

I have been trying to underline a multiline label but I am not able to do that.

I have referred [to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652163/draw-underlined-strikethrough-text-multiline-string) but this doesn't seem to help me.

How can be done without using NSAttributedString and coreText?

Comment: You could try uiwebview and use html but no way to do it in simple uilabel

Comment: @xs2bush: What if I don't want to use a webview. Is there any other option that I have?

Comment: have you tried refering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel/7186610#7186610

Comment: @DShah: Yes, I have tried that..but doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some of these open source projects from GitHub which are like `UILabel`'s but support an attributed string:

[`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) or [`OHAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

Answer (score 1):

Following steps can be helpful.

1. Extend UILable OR UIView.
2. Implement `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`
3. In that method get context using `CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
4. Set text you want to set using this.

   ```
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   CGContextSetTextMatrix(context,CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,pageSize.height));
   CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
   CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 30, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
   char *str=(char*)[@"TEXT" UTF8String];
   CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context,476/2-200,673/2+100,str,strlen(str));
   ```
5. Set Line using this code.

   `CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3);`
6. Draw line using this code.

   CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
   CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, thisX, thisY);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, thatX,thatY);
   CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

Hope above collected segments of code helps you....