# Multiline attributed string with strikethrough

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a label with:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

And I'm trying to make text of this label strikethrough with:

```
let index: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: label.text!)
index.addAttributes([NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], range: NSMakeRange(0, index.length))
label.textColor = UIColor.red
label.attributedText = index
```

Is it true that attributed string is not working with multilines or with labels with numberOfLines set to 0? And if so, how to make multiline text strikethrough?

Comment: Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652163/draw-underlined-strikethrough-text-multiline-string

Comment: Yes you are right. Generally it won't work with multiline. It's worth looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550732/font-with-strike-through-it

Comment: @SivajeeBattina thanks. It sounds like not bad decision, I'll try it and tell if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two solutions. They are based on @SivajeeBattina answer.

First one is to strike out text with help of http://adamvarga.com/strike/.

```
private func returnStrikedOutTextFromString(_ str: String) -> String {
    var newString = ""

    let normal = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя "
    let strikethrough = "А̶Б̶В̶Г̶Д̶Е̶Ё̶Ж̶З̶И̶Й̶К̶Л̶М̶Н̶О̶П̶Р̶С̶Т̶У̶Ф̶Х̶Ц̶Ч̶Ш̶Щ̶Ъ̶Ы̶Ь̶Э̶Ю̶Я̶а̶б̶в̶г̶д̶е̶ё̶ж̶з̶и̶й̶к̶л̶м̶н̶о̶п̶р̶с̶т̶у̶ф̶х̶ц̶ч̶ш̶щ̶ъ̶ы̶ь̶э̶ю̶я̶ ̶̶"

    for i in 0..<str.characters.count {

        let range: Range<String.Index> =
                normal.range(of: str
                        .substring(to: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i + 1))
                        .substring(from: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)))!
        let index: Int = normal.distance(from: normal.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)

        newString = String(format: "%@%@", newString,
                NSLocalizedString(strikethrough
                        .substring(to: strikethrough.index(strikethrough.startIndex, offsetBy: index + 1))
                        .substring(from: strikethrough.index(strikethrough.startIndex, offsetBy: index)),
                        comment: ""))

    }

    return newString

}
```

And second one is: https://github.com/GuntisTreulands/UnderLineLabel

Answer (score 8):

Works fine with multiline if you add NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName before:

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (object?.title)!)
attributeString.addAttribute(NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, value: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
```

Comment: How did you find out that `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` is needed?

Comment: Accidentally :-) I've found an example in a discussion, concerning underlying multiline string in tvOS. In this discussion a guy was curious, why everyone had this problem when he hadn't. And he showed his code. The only difference was in this Baseline attribute. So, I tried this on a strikethrough multiline string and it started to work.

Comment: What a story! Thanks for finding time.

Comment: Thank you!, I was looking for errors that did not exist until I realized my tasks where indeed completed, just not represented by the strikethrough when they were multilined.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like,

```
 let index: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lbl.text!)
    index.addAttributes([NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], range: NSMakeRange(0, index.length))
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.red
    lbl.attributedText = index
```

because `index` is your mutable string! not title!

And you can not use `strike through` with `multi line` label.

If you want `strike through` effect in multiple lines then you can use `UITextView` instead of label!

Comment: Are you sure your answer is working, I tried with index and it's not working. Note, label has multiline text. Your answer can't provide solution to this question as OP wants strike on multiline text

Comment: It will work if it is single line! There is one mistake in OP, index is mutable string not title! so i have correct that! @Krunal

Comment: thank you, @Lion. you are right. it is my typo, because I have two different labels that need to strikethrough. but I still have the same question :)

Comment: @kotvaska : you can use `UITextView` instead of label, if you want text with strike through and multilines both!

Answer (score 0):

Write it like,

```
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0
    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.label.text!)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    self.label.attributedText = attributeString
```

Working at my end.

[image]

Comment: thank you,  but I've tried it and it doesn't work for me

Comment: See my edited answer. Its working for multiline text.